# Setting source files for Sonarlint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

Is there a way to define the sourcefiles (and/or the excludefiles) with sonarlint? There is a scanner-properties tab, but I have found no documentation on the available properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude source files using the scanner-properties tab.
Here is the documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: I've tried to use these properties, but they didnt seem to work. It looks like the plugin can't handle multiple properties well (at least exclude and include combined). In the sonarlint console it looked like the properties were concatenated or something. Depending on the order of the properties it behaves different too. To circumvent this I have configured it to only use exclusions (one property: sonar.exclusions with value "**/lib-ext/**/*,**/target/**/*,**/expression/**/*" which works for me.